# C# HttpListener sending image to javascript / jQuery client

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I would like to send an image to a Javascript client and render it on the HTML5 canvas.
The client requests an image with a jQuery .post command and the HttpListener server would send it back.
How would I format an image file for transmission in C# and how would I decode the information to display the image using Javascript?

Comment: base64 comes to mind - though I'm sure binary data would be possible

Comment: do you have an example that shows both the C# server side code and the javascript client side code?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Converted bytes to base64 in C# server:

```
 using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filenamer))
                                {
                                    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                                        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                                        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                                        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                                        resendBack = base64String;  
                                    }
                                }
```

And in Javascript client, to render image on canvas:

```
 var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + imgData;
img.onload = function() {

        ctx.drawImage(img, xCorner, yCorner, width, height);
    }
```

where imgData is what the client gets from the server using a post request, a base64 string